# Array 2D printed in precise ascending order without using sort method?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print numbers in a 2d array in ascending order without the use of any sorting technique. Here is my code:

```
public class ArraySort2D 
{   
    public static void main(String s)
    {
        int[][] arr={ {4,3,2,7,1}, {7,5,4,6,3}};

        for(int k=0; k<=1; k++) 
        {       
            for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j=1; j<arr.length-i; j++)
                {
                    if(arr[k][j-1]>arr[k][j])
                    {
                        int dummy=arr[k][j-1];
                        arr[k][j-1]=arr[k][j];
                        arr[k][j]=dummy;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int p=0; p<arr.length; p++)
        {
            for(int g=0; g<arr[p].length; g++)
            {  
                System.out.println(arr[p][g]);      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the output as:

1 2 3 4 7
3 4 5 6 7

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: When you loop over i and j, shouldn't the upper bound be `arr[k].length` rather than `arr.length` ?

Comment: Jim Lewis....its still not working by changing it to arr[k].length

Answer (score 0):

I am using a dumb sorting algorithm but you should be able to easily adapt whatever sorting algorithm you want to the sorting method i use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr= {  {4,3,2,7,1},
                    {7,5,4,6,3}
                };
    for(int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
        sortArray(arr[index]);

    printArray(arr);

}//main method

public static int[] sortArray(int[] ogArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ogArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i + 1 < ogArray.length && ogArray[i] > ogArray[i + 1])
        {
            int temp = ogArray[i + 1];
            ogArray[i + 1] = ogArray[i];
            ogArray[i] = temp;
            i = -1;
        }
    }

    return ogArray;
}

public static void printArray(int[][] temp)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < temp[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(temp[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
1234734567
```